# How to Share Screen with Red5 using C#?

Tags: c#, red5

Anyone have any idea or sample project "How to use Red5 with C#?"

Comment: Could you be specific on what you want to achieve with Red5?

Comment: actually, I am developing on C# and I want to connect with Red5 to share screen with other machine.